# Having an issue in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue in MySQL query that i have to pull some record from a view with the order by clause from attended_date, but even there might be some data without attended_date filled so how can i get it done

example :

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_getengineerreview 
WHERE reference_number ='xxs/xxx/00256' 
ORDER BY attended_date ASC;
```

this gives the record what is available (thats correct) but the null recorded value print in top, but i want to have in the bottom (when the attended_date is null)

Output is below

```
| Technician Name   | Start Date / Time     | End Date / Time     | Technician Remarks |
|-------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|--------------------|
| Kasun Chathuranga | 2016-10-04 - 10:49:13 | -                   |                    |
| Kasun Chathuranga | 2016-09-06 - 17:17:02 | 2016-09-22-02:16:23 | not powering       |
```

Comment: Please use a more explicit title.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_getengineerreview 
WHERE reference_number ='xxs/xxx/00256' 
ORDER BY (attended_date IS NOT NULL) DESC, attended_date ASC
```

Play with the `ASC`/`DESC` if result is not the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, this will surely solve your problem.

Thanks,

Happy Coding.

```html
SELECT * 
FROM vw_getengineerreview 
WHERE reference_number ='xxs/xxx/00256' 
ORDER BY ISNULL(attended_date),attended_date ASC;
```